# Add value or percentage in contingency table plot

Tags: r

I would like to put in each box from the ploted contingency table, the value obtained by the table.
[image]

The following image represent the contingency table

[image]

Te following code is how to display the contingency table:

```
> svm.video.table2<-table(pred=svm.video.pred2, true= filteredDataFinal$rate)
> svm.video.table2
```

An this one is how to plot that table

```
plot(svm.video.table2)
```

Comment: As we don't have your data `svm.video.pred2` and `filteredDataFinal`, it would have been great if you had run `dput(svm.video.table2)` and added the result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

And adhoc approach would be:

```
text(x = 0.23, y = 0.55, "10")
text(x = 0.23, y = 0.67, "2")
text(x = 0.64, y = 0.94, "1")
text(x = 0.64, y = 0.45, "9")
text(x = 0.92, y = 0.44, "4")
```

---

PS: I generated the data to make your example reproducible with `svm.video.table2 <- as.table(matrix(c(10, 1, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4), ncol = 3))`